# add simple radio button in Checkout page in PAYMENT METHOD

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

[image]

I want to add new radio button after CASH ON DELIVERT in one page Checkout page in PAYMENT METHOD.
If click on radio button then show email id.

Comment: modify in template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

Comment: Why dont you use Cash on delivery payment method default available in magento and make modification to display email address via Jquery.

Comment: @Nits if I use payment method cash on delivery then in admin panel place order as cash on delivery but i want us order as email address

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

Your phtml file don't add any custom **radio button try with your cash on delivery only**

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .box{
            padding: 20px;
            display: none;
            margin-top: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).attr("value")=="email"){
                $(".box").not(".email").hide();
                $(".email").show();
            }

        });
    });
    </script>


 <div>
        <label><input type="radio" name="email" value="email"> Show</label>

    </div>
    <div class="email box">your mail</div>
```